# org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

Due to the fact that I'm using an abstract class, I get such error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected! 
Both private final com.life.book.domain.event.EventType com.life.book.domain.command.ObjectCommand.eventType 
and private final com.life.book.domain.event.EventType com.life.book.domain.command.UpdateObjectCommand.eventType 
map to the same field name eventType! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!
```

My classes:

```kotlin
abstract class ObjectCommand(
    open var eventType: EventType?
)

@Document(collection = "COMMAND")
data class UpdateObjectCommand(
    val description: String?,
    override var eventType: EventType?
) : ObjectCommand(eventType)

enum class EventType {
    CREATED, UPDATED
}
```

The solution might be to use a different name instead of the `eventType` name in the `UpdateObjectCommand` class. But then the database will have two fields with the same purpose. Maybe there is another way?

There is `Disambiguate using @Field annotation` in the description of the error, but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a sec since I have delt with what looks like Mongo DB and Spring Boot (I could be off base here). The @Field annotation is applied to fields in your class that have the @Document annotation.

You can add information to the @Field annotation like the serialized name of the field, or if its written when null. @Field in most cases does not need to be applied to a field unless you are dealing with enums. Mongo does not know how to store an enum, so you must add the @Field annotation to specify that it needs to be stored as a string.

https://blog.tericcabrel.com/using-mongodb-with-spring-boot-project-part-1/

From tericcabrel.com:

> @Field is used to enhance the property by changing the type; like our case, MongoDB doesn't support Enum, so we need to tell Mongo to store this property's value as a string. When retrieving the data from the collection, the value will be returned back as an Enum. You can also provide a different name for the property in MongoDB.